# How to create a <a-sky></a-sky> image with right size

Tags: aframe

A-Frame sky default radius= 5,000

diameter=10,000

So if I was to create a equirectangular image in photoshop or other program, which size should I use? 10,000 x 5,000 pixels or 10,000 x 5,000 meters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter much. The exported size of the image only counts for resolution. You can balance between having a higher-resolution image or saving on file size over the network. Keep it at a minimum resolution that you are satisfied with.